# Как реализовать мультиязычность на сайте Wordpress с применением Carbon Fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, настройка, перевод

Есть сайт на WP

В качестве основного инструмента для вывода опций использую Carbon Fields 2.2

Вот так задаю поле

```
Field::make('text', 'mirtecon_after_main_slogan_text', __('Text after the main slogan', 'mirtecon')),
```

Вот так делаю  вывод  поля

```
<?php
            if (carbon_get_theme_option('mirtecon_after_main_slogan_text')) {
                echo carbon_get_theme_option('mirtecon_after_main_slogan_text');
            }
            ?>
```

Вопрос: как можно подружить данный инструмент с плагинами мультиязычности?

Уточняю: в перевод  должно  попасть то что вводится в качестве значения в поле.

Comment: Carbon Fields поддерживает WPML: https://carbonfields.net/docs/advanced-topics-wpml-support/

Comment: Не знаю  может  я что-то  делаю  не так но  у меня сами поля в админке переводятся и их  перевод  готов // вот только WPML не видит значения введенные в поле.